# Programming a Line Chart in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I was given a task to programmatically generate this chart:

[image: chart].

So far, I have found these [resources](http://excelvbatutor.com/index.php/excel-vba-2010-lesson-24-creating-charts-and-graphs/)
and [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx) for generating charts using VBA.

This is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheet1.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Top = 10
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Left = 10
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers

ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Table1")
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

However, I'm not quite getting the output that I need.

This is an example data table:

[image: My Sample Table]

Notes:

1. Orange line - Upper and lower limit of each item.
2. Blue Dotted line - value of each item.

Comment: As we've no idea what your desired output is, your best bet is to record yourself creating the chart. You can then examine the output of that recording and convert it into something useful/reusable.

Comment: @CLR its in my first line of sentence. I modified question and provided a hyperlink of what output i need.

Comment: Have you tried recording yourself creating the chart?

Comment: @CLR i am currently trying to. but I'm really clueless about creating charts via VBA. They want it to be generated with a button click (How Lazy of them -_-)

Comment: Why don't you show us the output chart from your current code, so we can better help with where it is going wrong? This is currently too broad as we don't know what you're specifically stuck with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the following comes close. You'll need to alter the range (or set it up to dynamically find it - that's another question) and set the cell range for where the title is etc. but I think this should get you going:

**Excel 2013 version:**

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
With ActiveChart

    ' Set the source
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$D$6")

    ' Set the title
    .ChartTitle.Text = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value

    ' Format the labels to 45 degrees
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45

    ' Set Line 2 to Orange dash, no marker
    With .FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
        .DashStyle = msoLineDash
        .Parent.Parent.MarkerStyle = -4142
        'add other formatting here
    End With

    ' Set Line 3 to Orange dash, no marker
    With .FullSeriesCollection(3).Format.Line
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
        .DashStyle = msoLineDash
        .Parent.Parent.MarkerStyle = -4142
        'add other formatting here
    End With

End With
```

I obtained this by recording a macro and then adding in a `With` to strip out unnecessary use of `.Activechart`. You could always `Set` it if you need to refer to it later but that again, is for another question. You could also create a loop to take out one of the pieces of code for the `.FullSeriesCollection()` if you wanted to refine further.

**Excel 2007/2010 version:** (with looping and visibility workaround to allow colour change)

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With ActiveChart
    .ApplyLayout (1)
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet1'!$A$1:$D$6")
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 45
    .ChartTitle.Text = Sheet1.Range("B1").Value

    For scoln = 2 To 3
        With .SeriesCollection(scoln)
            .Format.Line.Visible = False
            .Format.Line.Visible = True
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = 683236
            .Format.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSysDash
            .MarkerStyle = -4142
        End With
    Next

    With .SeriesCollection(1)
         .MarkerStyle = 8
         .MarkerSize = 8
     End With
End With
```

Comment: im getting an error on `.FullSeriesCollection` -> `Method or data member not found`

Comment: apparently upon further research (if I understood them correctly) `AddChart2` and this `.FullSeriesCollection` found on Ms Office 2013 onwards. I'm using 2010.

Comment: I've added a version compatible with earlier Office versions to my answer.

Comment: Thank You. I'm already getting it going even before you posted another answer. but really thank you :)